# Why does accessing and mutating a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary in parallel not result in exceptions/crashes?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, clr, race-condition

Can someone either explain or point me to some documentation that can explain to me why this code doesn't throw any exceptions:

```
var d = new Dictionary<object, object>();
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(new Action[] {
    () => {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 1024, i => {
            d.Add(new object(), new object());
        });
    },
    () => {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 1024, i => {
            d.TryGetValue(new object(), out _);
        });
    },
}, a => a());
```

I tried running this on my 8-core computer expecting something would throw an exception about an invalid operation or null reference, etc., but it never does.  Though I end up with a dictionary that has the wrong number of elements, how is it that this doesn't throw and exception and/or crash?

Comment: According to the documentation `Add` throws if the key is already in the dictionary which will not happen since you create a new object each time.  And `TryGetValue` is designed to not throw.  So exactly what exceptions would you expect?

Comment: @juharr one would expect re-balancing happening from two threads at the same time to cause some havoc... but since OP doing just 1000 iterations and `Parallel.ForEach` not necessary to even run enough threads to lead to real trouble it is hard to reliably trigger. Also incorrect data overall is far more common outcome of unprotected multithread access but OP does not care of correctness at all.

Comment: A race condition by defintion means it may not cause an issue on most runs. Have you run it 10million times to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because something isn't thread safe doesn't mean using it from multiple threads will cause it to throw an exception. The Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class is not thread safe and only expects to be used by one thread at a time. It likely doesn't include any checks for what threads are accessing it at the same time as that would be too expensive. It simply assumes that there is only one thread accessing it at a time.

Comment: I'm guessing this all comes down to 1. reads and writes to reference types and ints, etc., being atomic and 2. garbage collection.  Unlike a C implementation which might attempt to free something while another thread might be using it and lead to use after free and/or accessing uninitialized memory, I guess C# doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mutating a non-thread-safe component from multiple threads concurrently guarantees neither an exception nor a crash. Actually it guarantees absolutely nothing. The behavior of the component becomes officially "undefined", which means that anything can happen, including nothing bad happening at all. But *if* something unpleasant happens, then you can't go to the vendor and fill a bug report, asking for the bug to be fixed. Because there is no bug. The vendor could reply to your request with something along these lines:

> Dear customer, the seal is broken, the warranty is void. You've chosen to enter the big black forest of undefined territory, where no rules apply, and now you are on your own.